# Update data from html table using angular js and radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML table with some data that is coming from a web service and I'm using Angular, then I have 3 radio buttons to display the top 10, 20 and 30 records from my data source. The 3 buttons should call a web service for each one, the web services are already working but I don't know how to make those radio buttons to display the new data in the table, the structure of that table doesn't change and because I'm using Angular I can avoid refreshing the whole page.

Does any one have an example for this?

My table is in a differente div with its own controller that displays some data:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrlOne">
  <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
    <td>{{d.field1}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

In another div I have my radio buttons:

```
   <div class="radio">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="top30">TY Top 30 Categories</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="top20">TY Top 20 Brands</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="top10">TY Top 10 Suppliers</label>
   </div>
```

No controller yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the radio group to select the data model like this..

```
 <div class="radio">
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="tableVal" value="data10">Show top 10</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="tableVal" value="data20">Show top 20</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="tableVal" value="data30">Show top 30</label>
</div>  
<table ng-if="tableVal === 'data10'">
 <tr ng-repeat="d in data10">
  <td>{{d}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table ng-show="tableVal === 'data20'">
 <tr ng-repeat="d in data20">
  <td>{{d}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table ng-show="tableVal === 'data30'">
 <tr ng-repeat="d in data30">
  <td>{{d}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

A sample of your dataset in controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tableVal = 'data10'
  $scope.data10 = ['10-first','10-second','10-third','10-fourth'];
  $scope.data20 = ['20-first','20-second','20-third','20-fourth'];
  $scope.data30 = ['30-first','30-second','30-third','30-fourth'];
});
```

Comment: Thank's for your time!

Let me try and see if I have any question :)

Comment: The three web services should be declared inside the $watch?
@BrianBaker

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Are you going to get the whole model on page load and filter with the radio buttons or call the respective webservice when a radio button is pushed?

Comment: Actually what I'm doing to avoid performance issues is to load the three web services at the same time, I create three tables because the structure of the data change so I want to hide the first two and then hide depending on my radio button selection.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Since you'll already have the data model present then all you need to do is add a filter to the ng-repeat. Something like:                `<tr ng-repeat="d in data|limitTo: filterVal">`. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/j1hQiA79ssz1Rp7nkrT2) is an example.

Comment: You won't need the watch in this case BTW.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

So then, ¿How can I achive this, I saw the ng-show and ng-hide directive but now my problem is where to manage the condition, in a controller or ng-if.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100522/discussion-between-brian-baker-and-kennechu).

Comment: Updated answer to reflect dynamically showing tables